How to get a sequential x-ray map that shows task progression through different aws services
I have an aws x-ray map that looks like this:

The state machine goes like lambda => s3 => lamdba but the x-ray map does not show this. This is okay when it is one state machine, but when you add serveral state machines plus event bridge and other services things look more messy. How can I have the map showing a sequential diagram of how the tasks progress through the various services?
